# C++ is getter function equivalent to volatile

Tags: c++

It occurs to me that, I should reword my question. Is there any difference between these two implementation when the compiler does its optimization?

Sorry about the confusion. I do understand the importance of encapsulation and that is not what i am asking about.

```
class A
{
public:
 int get_data{return m_data;}

private:
 int m_data;
}

class B
{
public:
 int get_data{return m_data;}

private:
 volatile int m_data;
}
```

Comment: I think in this case, if this were in a header, the `inline` would be implied.

Comment: Define same, there are a lot of reasons to do a getter vs exposing the variable itself

Comment: Am not too familiar with `volatile` is there anything about it that prevents outsiders changing the value?

Comment: if use the getter, do i have to worry about m_data got cached in the process?

Comment: Rather than programming by random guessing, it might be more productive to learn the language systematically, and e.g. understand what `volatile` is for.

Comment: What do you understand by `volatile`? What makes you think that having a "getter" would imply `volatile`?

Comment: @FrankLiu cached? unless the variable was `const` i wouldnt expect that. And even in the case of `const`

Comment: encapsulation apart. does compiler optimize the getter function to cache the returned value?

Comment: It can. And probably does.

Comment: my understanding of volatile is that the processor will read/write directly to the memory. Without volatile, the compiler may optimize the code that the value might get cached in some internal register. Does use a getter prevent the caching without declare m_data volatile.

Comment: @KerrekSB Rather than sound condescending, it might be more productive to give some constructive suggestions. like you know everything.

Comment: @FrankLiu _Without volatile, the compiler may optimize the code that the value might get cached in some internal register_ - And how would introducing a getter method prevent the compiler from doing so? As pointed out by the answers, the two concepts (`volatile` and getter functions) are completely unrelated, but I'm still curious as to what you think the link between the two would be.

Comment: @FrankLiu: I gave a constructive suggestion: Learn systematically what the rules are. I don't pretend to, or in fact actually know what they are, but if I wanted to use `volatile`, I'd look up what it means and how it behaves, rather than guess that sprinkling it into some random code would have some kind of effect. (There is in fact a non-trivial, subtle place for `volatile` in the C++ memory model, but it's unlikely to be useful.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A function call does not imply that access to this variable cannot be re-ordered or optimized out. It can be optimized and re-ordered, and most compilers will probably perform such optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if accessing a data member via a getter is the same as making it public and declare it volatile ?

No.  BTW correct usage of volatile in C and C++ is so rare that I wonder if you are mistaken and think it has something to do with threads, it hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile is mostly used in code which interacts with memory mapped IO etc.
It prevents the compiler from most optimizations and therefore CAN lead to the desired behaviour in multi-threaded code, but its intent is to decorate memory which the compiler knows nothing about.

[Here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484) is an article from Herb Sutter about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for getters is the old story about encapsulation.
[Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

No matter what keyword you use, the encapsulation rule will be broken if you are not using a getter

And as everyone else has pointed out, volatile does not do what you think it does.